# AWK - Add previous line to beginning of next two lines

Tags: awk

I have a document that looks like this:

```
Bob:
This is my line
This is also my line
Alfred:
What a great day!
What should we do!
Jess:
Its so hot
Lets go to the Beach
```

The format is always the same, it's always

```
speaker
line1
line2
speaker
line1
line2
```

There is never additional lines, etc.

I want the 'speaker' to be at the beginning of every line, so in my example it is:

```
Bob: This is my line
Bob: This is also my line
Alfred: What a great day!
Alfred: What should we do!
Jess: Its so hot
Jess: Lets go to the Beach
```

I've tried extracting every 'nth' line using awk

```
awk '{if (NR % 3 == 1) print $0}'
```

but I'm not sure how to add it back to the beginning of the next two lines.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is the format `Bob:` like in the *example* or  `Bob` like in the *it's always* part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk 'NR%3==1{ name=$0; next } { print name, $0 }' file
```

If the condition is true, save the record to variable `name` and continue with the `next` record.

Print `name` and current record otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

I would change the logic. Get the latest speaker and then tack it in front of all other lines until another speaker appears. That might be more robust, should you ever have just one line of text, or more than two.

```
awk '/^[[:alpha:]]+:$/ {speaker=$1;next} {print speaker,$0}' file
```

Comment: @lumo, yes, it has `:`, right before the `$`.

Comment: You could leave out the `^[[:alpha:]]+`, and just make it `/:$/`. Then you would also have no issue if the speaker has a double-name or surname or so.

Comment: @pLumo, the speaker might say something like, "there are two reasons:<new line>reason one, reason two". And you don't want to parse the whole first sentence as a speaker.

Comment: That is also true, so relying on the `:` is generally not the best idea then? What if he said `Look:<new line>Here it is.` ?

Comment: @pLumo in that case *Look:* woud be considered a speaker. If the positioning (every third line) works for you always, then choose the other answer. If you'd rather do the speaker-based, then you have to make sure you have a speaker. That can be done in many ways, even tagging those lines based on a dictionary of names. That would be a completely new question though. For what you've asked, at least one of the existing two answers should do it. Then you'd have to do some more tailoring to adjust the code exactly to your input.

Comment: Sure, but I did not ask that question :-)

Comment: Haha, it did look (to me) you were the OP.

Answer (score 0):

With the file format as stated, we can do it using `sed` as follows

```
sed -e '
  h;N;s/\n/ /
  n;H;g;s// /
' file
```